# Which weapon do I draw by default when combat starts, if I have several weapons which I can wield?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons

I'm playing a ranger in a 5e D&D campaign with dual-weapon fighting proficiency.

Assuming I draw *some* weapon **when combat starts, which weapon do I draw by default (e.g., bow, daggers, do I pick)?**

**Does this change case-by-case?**

Comment: Related, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98042/do-you-start-combat-with-your-weapon-drawn-when-combat-is-not-expected

Comment: @MichałPolitowski see this as sort of a follow up question to that one. There the question is do I automatically draw a weapon. My question is what weapon do I draw.

Comment: @Jappieman The consensus on that question seems to be that it's situational and 5e doesn't go into this detail. As it stands I don't understand how this question isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not automatically draw a weapon, but you can use your free object interaction on your turn to draw a weapon of your choice. So, it's completely up to you.

Comment: 5e doesn't have "free actions". Creatures can interact with one object as part of their movement for the turn, and this can include drawing a weapon.

Comment: @MarkCogan: so.... That would be a "free" action then, no? FFS.

Comment: In the general senses of the words "free" and "action", yes. But "action" has a specific meaning in the context of the 5e combat rules, and "free action" had a specific meaning in prior editions of the game. In a strict rules sense -- and this was a rules question -- a character cannot "use their free action" to do anything, because they don't have a "free action". So your answer could be improved by using language that more accurately describes the actual rules for drawing weapons in 5e .

Comment: 5e allows you **one** object interaction per turn (PHB p. 190).  It's only "free" in the sense that it does not ordinarily require your action/bonus/movement to be used, but it's still restricted.  As the PHB notes in that same section, some of those interactions may change (situationally) to require an action at the DM's discretion.