# Can a two-weapon combatant draw both weapons at once?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, actions, two-weapon-fighting

The only rule regarding this that I've managed to find is (PHB p190):

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or you could draw your weapon as part of the same action you use to attack.

If a PC has two weapons (dual wield), does he draw one or both?

Comment: Related: [Drawing and sheathing a weapon in 5e, and the actions required](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50526/33569), [Drawing and sheathing weapons as one item interaction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109882/33569), [Do you start combat with your weapon drawn when combat is not expected?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98042/33569), [Does Sheathing and Unsheathing Separate Weapons Count As a Full Action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/81029/33569)

Comment: [Related to your shield](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49376/22566), which is a separate question to this one.  Suggest you go back and read the bit about armor to understand your concern about the shield, versus the weapon.  PHB p 144 and p 146.  Then edit out your question about the shield (which is separate from your weapon question) and then if need be ask that as a separate question once you have reviewed the armor/shield material.

Comment: More on shields here: https://youtu.be/zEsjPQeWmd8

Answer (score 21):

## You can only draw one weapon

The [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn) state:

> You can also interact with **one object** or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or you could draw **your weapon** as part of the same action you use to attack.

When you choose to attack, you can draw a single weapon as part of that same action. Note how the rules specifically says "one object" and "your weapon". Also the sentence directly following this passage makes this more explicit:

> If you want to interact with a **second object**, you need to use your
> action. Some magic items and other special objects always require an
> action to use, as stated in their descriptions.

Drawing one weapon is one interaction with one object. Trying to draw the second weapon would be a second interaction with a second object and thus it would require an action to perform.

#### There is a feat that will let you do this though

The [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/dual-wielder) feat (PHB, p. 165) has a few benefits, one of which is:

> You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

If you had this feat, you would then be able to draw both of your weapons as part of a single Attack action.

Answer (score 7):

You can only interact with **a single object** for free on your turn. This means you can only draw a single weapon for free (unless you have the *Dual Wielder* feat) and drawing and sheathing 2 different weapons count as interactions with 2 objects.